Visual Studio Extension using external library produces "Could not load file or assembly" at runtime
I have a basic Solution as per below:

I have setup the Solution Properties so that VisGit depends on VisGit.Core. VisGit.Core has also been imported as a library into VisGit. It compiles fine with no errors. However, when I try to run it in the VS test environment, I get:
Could not load file or assembly 'VisGit.Core, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I'm guessing its not building the VisGit.Core lib to the relevant test environment location? Not sure how to check that. What I've tried:

Adding below to VisGit.AssemblyInfo.cs

[assembly: ProvideCodeBase(AssemblyName = "VisGit.Core")]


The usual clean, delete bin/obj, restart VS stuff.

Adding VisGit.Core to vsixmanifest>Assets


No joy. Any advice would be appreciated.
Github code here
UPDATE:
I've also found where the temp extension is built to. VisGit.Core is clearly there:

UPDATE 2:
Looks like VS is looking for the library in the wrong place? Ran fuslogvw.exe and got the following:
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (20/06/2024 @ 18:39:07) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = VisGit.Core, PublicKeyToken=null
 (Partial)
WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an assembly:
WRN: Assembly Name: VisGit.Core, PublicKeyToken=null | Domain ID: 1
WRN: A partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is provided.
WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect assembly.
WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual identity for the assembly,
WRN: that consists of the simple name, version, culture, and public key token.
WRN: See whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and common solutions to this issue.
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = devenv.exe
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\stigz\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\17.0_83cd348aExp\devenv.exe.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/VisGit.Core.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/VisGit.Core/VisGit.Core.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/PublicAssemblies/VisGit.Core.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/PublicAssemblies/VisGit.Core/VisGit.Core.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/VisGit.Core.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/VisGit.Core/VisGit.Core.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TestWindow/VisGit.Core.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TestWindow/VisGit.Core/VisGit.Core.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Platform/Debugger/VisGit.Core.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Platform/Debugger/VisGit.Core/VisGit.Core.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/VisGit.Core.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/VisGit.Core/VisGit.Core.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x64/VisGit.Core.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x64/VisGit.Core/VisGit.Core.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/VisGit.Core.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/VisGit.Core/VisGit.Core.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/PublicAssemblies/VisGit.Core.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/PublicAssemblies/VisGit.Core/VisGit.Core.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/VisGit.Core.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/VisGit.Core/VisGit.Core.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TestWindow/VisGit.Core.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TestWindow/VisGit.Core/VisGit.Core.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Platform/Debugger/VisGit.Core.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Platform/Debugger/VisGit.Core/VisGit.Core.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/VisGit.Core.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/VisGit.Core/VisGit.Core.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x64/VisGit.Core.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x64/VisGit.Core/VisGit.Core.EXE.
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.


From looking at your solution tree diagram, it seems that  VisGit.Core.dll file is placed separately at the project VisGit's root level.
How do you setup VisGit to reference VisGit.Core? Please check your VisGit.csproj file to see whether the VisGit.Core.dll was successfully referenced.
<Reference>xxx\xxx\VisGit.Core.dll</Reference>

If no .dll file referenced, please try to use Add Reference to use external library by right clicking VisGit project->Add->Reference.
1.Add Project Reference

2.Add Assemblies

After doing that, you can see references from here:

For more information, please refer to doc:Add or remove references
Hope it can help you.
UPDATE
I have found a similar error information from this ticket

There’s another tricky thing. Because you don’t use any classes in the Material Design assemblies, your script assembly doesn’t load those assemblies. It’s the XAML parser that uses the Material Design assemblies and therefore tries to load them. The problem is that, because it’s not your assembly that loads them, .NET looks for the Material Design assemblies in the wrong place.

Please try to modify the code like this to see if the issue persists:
using VisGit.Core.ViewModels;

namespace VisGit.Views
{
    public partial class MainView : UserControl
    {
        public MainView()
        {
            InitializeMaterialDesign();
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void InitializeMaterialDesign()
        {
            
            var modelDemo = new MainViewModel();
        }


In solution settings , I make VisGit depend on VisGit.Core. As per OP, I imported VisGit.Core exactly via the means you indicated (add project reference). There is no <Reference Include="VisGit.Core" /> but there is:
<ProjectReference Include="..\VisGit.Core\VisGit.Core.csproj">       <Project>{54fea1ba-85cf-4ada-8a10-ca63f6707e1a}</Project>       <Name>VisGit.Core</Name>
I have updated the OP with a link to the full Github code that may help you.

Cloned your code and built them from  right click Project->Build or Start without Debugging, no errors and intellisense can detect VisGit.Core normally.Test result Could you share your repro steps of building?

Thanks for your help. Please try again with the updated repo code (as may have messed things up with trying to show two separate issues through it). It builds fine, but the problem is when I try to run in debug mode or without debugger. I've made a video highlighting relevant code and also showing the build/problem: https://youtu.be/TusIuPhWB-4

Also - I've updated the OP with more helpful info.

Be able to reproduce the same with you. Please check the update to see if it can help.

That nailed it - thanks! I'm guessing it's just the referencing VisGit.Core in code behind rather than in xaml  that fixes the assembly error? Is this specific to VS Extensions or is it a broader WPF issue? If the latter - it's quite a major one! Where should I post a MS bug report? In the meantime, I'll just use this dirty hack. Thanks again.

I referenced  a custom class in xaml in WPF project by the same way and it worked fine. I checked the following docs:Requirements for a Custom Class as a XAML Element and Mapping example. It seems it is not a broader WPF issue.

Ah OK. Then I wonder what caused it? Only academic interest, really. Thanks for all your help on my various issues!
